# The Lockheed Martin SR-72 will fly at Mach 6. Using the earth curvature formula, can someone calculate the negative G’s on the pilot flying level?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

SR 72 Pilot flying level at Mach 6 will have to nose down constantly to remain at a given altitude while flying over the earth’s curvature. What will be the centrifugal force (negative G’s) on his body while doing this? I’ve also read that Lockheed Martin has plans for airplanes that will fly at 14,000 mph. If that is true, I have the same question for that speed.

Answer (score 2):

The acceleration you want is $v^2/r$ where $v$ is the speed and $r$ the radius of the circle, which is here similar to the radius of the earth, about 6371 km. So taking the speed of sound as 340 m/s, mach 6 is a speed of 2040 m/s, and the acceleration is
$$
a = \frac{2040^2}{6371000} \; {\rm m/s}^2 \simeq 0.65 {\rm m/s}^2
$$
This about $0.067 g$. The pilot will not notice this small effect, I think, since presumably the aircraft is buffeted by the air much more than this.

I leave the other calculation to you!